# How can I get the type of a component passed as property or as ref ?

Tags: react-native

Know anyone a way to check the component type of a ref property?

Exmpl. fantasy react native code:

```
class A extends Component {
   render(){
      return(
         <ScrollView ref={(r)=>{this._parent = r}}>
            <ChildComponent parent={this._parent}/>
         </ScrollView>
      );
    }
 }

class ChildComponent extends Component{
    componentDidMount(){
       if(this.property.parent && this.property.parent.type == 'ScrollView') {
         ... whatever
       }
    }
    render(){
       return(
         ...
       )
    } 
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try the comparison like this :

```
this.property.parent instanceof ScrollView
```

Comment: 'instanceOf is undefined' - I tried the usual suspects like instanceOf, typeof, toString, constructor.name, ... without success.

Comment: did you try to simply remove quotes

Comment: this.property.parent.type === ScrollView

Comment: this.property.parent.type is undefined, but x instanceof y is the right way, or x typeof 'y' is correct too. Solved